# How to Use embeddableDocumentStore.DocumentDatabase.StartBackup(...) Third Parameter

Tags: ravendb, embedded-database

In RavenDB v2.5 a third parameter has been added to the StartBackup method.  How do you create/supply this third parameter?  Everything I found on the web only references two parameters.

```
embeddableDocumentStore.DocumentDatabase.StartBackup(string, bool, **DatabaseDocument**)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best reference is to looking on the RavenDB tests themselves:

https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/2.5/Raven.Tests/Storage/BackupRestore.cs#L69

```
db.StartBackup(BackupDir, false, new DatabaseDocument());
```

Comment: Accepted as answer because it helps me finish my code.  I still don't know what the parameter is for and what situations you would need to supply a parameter from another source.